# How To Modify .Net Assembly At Runtime And Keep These Changes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

**Hello,**

I just ask if there is a way in C#.Net to modify assembly at runtime,
What I mean
if I have a This class

```
public static class TimesTracker
{
    public static int Rest = 3;
}
```

Now, I need at runtime to change `Rest` to `2` but keep those changes.

So, next time I Open my program I find `Rest=2`.

I know, I can use configuration file, DB, ... but I just ask about this possibility

#### Background

I know about Replacing methods implementation at run time, Also about Invoking/compiling string code With Roslyn at runtime

Comment: With this level of information this is likely an x/y problem. Why do you need to do this? as its likely you may need to rethink what you want to do.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think eziriz software eg, IntelliLock uses this type of modifications to do some pieces of stuff I try to monitor what happens, but all I get is that assembly was changed, I know how to implement this it is not a complex topic: but with my implementation, I need a wrapper around the main assembly then in execution time I will call the internal compiled file `exe from string {roslyn}` to modify what I need then replace it with currently contained assembly, finally merge two assemblies again [since no restrictions on moving exe file while runtime], But this behavior makes antiv

Comment: @MichaelRandall So this is the same steps to developing trojans, and make any antivirus complains about what happened since this may execute code from remote and as you know this behavior signature defined in blacklist for most of the antivirus software , this is the same idea used in Rats eg, NjRat,... So What I need to know if there are any possibilities in .net to just change values in assembly without all those long and dangerous steps? you say it is x/y problem ? So How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. However I can't think of any use case.

I used [`Mono.Cecil`](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) before in a MSBuild target to modify assemblies on the fly and save back to disk.

Here is an example how what you asked could be done:

```
var filePath = "Assembly path";
var updatedFilePath = "Updated assembly path";

// Read assembly
using (var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(filePath))
{
    // Find type TimesTracker. This example was done in LINQPad, so TimesTracker is nested type inside UserQuery
    var type = assembly.MainModule.Types.SelectMany(t => t.NestedTypes).First(td => td.Name == "TimesTracker");
    // Find static constructor
    var cctor = type.Methods.First(md => md.Name == ".cctor");

    // Get IL
    var il = cctor.Body.GetILProcessor();

    // The IL of Rest = 3 is:
    // IL_0000: ldc.i4.3
    // IL_0001: stsfld int32 UserQuery / TimesTracker::Rest
    var op = il.Body.Instructions.First(i => i.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
    // Replace 3 with 7
    var newOp = il.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7);
    il.Replace(op, newOp);

    // Write updated to another assembly file
    assembly.Write(updatedFilePath);
}

// Load updated assembly into AppDomain
var updatedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(updatedFilePath);
// Use reflection to get value of Rest
var updatedType = updatedAssembly.DefinedTypes.First(t => t.Name.Contains("TimesTracker"));
var field = updatedType.GetField("Rest", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

// value is now 7
var value = (int)field.GetValue(null);
```

Note the above code can only modify:

```
public class TimesTracker
{ 
    public static int Rest = 3;
}
```

However, because C# doesn't allow to reload assemblies unless unload entire `AppDomain`, using/loading the updated assembly would be a challenge.

Comment: Thank you, I know about using Mono, I am sorry I did not mention that, anyway I will wait 3 days if no one  provide an answer I will mark this answer as an accepted answer.

Comment: But for use cases, I use this in a licensing system which user will run the program: at the first time the program will calculate GUID for Bios & Motherboard, then will call remote server to get a multipart license [PKey, LInfo] and this behavior will be allowed only once, so when user run this app again I can restrict running time/times even if user changes the system, I really do not need this type of licensing, but I think about its possibility and try to implement it in my free time, so may i will stick with my implementation

Comment: Given the user needs to call remote server already, I think using a backend service / database would be better than this kind of "local" counter in case it's compromised. Or if it has to be local maybe consider using windows registry?